# Access view helper directly with Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view in ember 1.10.0

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, htmlbars

This code worked in ember 1.7.0:

```js
 var ViewTemplateHelper = Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(templateString, options) {

  var dummy = Ember.View.extend({
    classNames: ['view-template'],
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile(templateString)
  });

  var view = dummy.create();

  if (options && options.hash) {
    options.hash.content = template;
  }

  // Hack to prevent appendChild error
  if (options.data.view._state === 'inDOM') {
    options.data.view.rerender();
    options.data.view.renderToBuffer();
  }

  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, view, options); // undefined is not a function
});

export
default ViewTemplateHelper;
```

But now in ember 1.10.0 is gives the `undefined is not a function` error.

I tried to use `Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.helperFunction.call`.

What do I miss?

Comment: What is the intent of this code? I feel like you always will hit some problems when upgrading the framework, since you're using some internal APIs.

Comment: I'm trying to use a template from an external API endpoint inside of a helper. So in a database somewhere there is the template (userTemplate) `User {{user.name}}` which I'm want to show via `{{view-template userTemplate}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem was not in a helper, but to use a component instead.

```js
// components/content-element.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export
default Ember.Component.extend({
  updateLayout: function() {
    var store = this.container.lookup('store:main');
    var projectId = this.get('project.id');
    store.find('contentElement', {
      key: this.get('key'),
      project_id: projectId
    }).then(function(contentElement) {
      if (!Ember.isEmpty(contentElement.get('firstObject.value'))) {
        var template = contentElement.get('firstObject.value');
        var compiled = Ember.Handlebars.compile(template);
        this.set('layout', compiled);
        this.rerender();
      }
    }.bind(this));
  }.observes('key').on('init')
});
```

We use the model `contentElement` for our templates. After setting the layout to the compiled Handlebars you have to run `this.rerender();`

For components you have to bind all to be used variables like this:

```
{{content-element key="name.of.element" project=project}}
```

In this case we use `project` in our dynamic template so we bound it. The `key` is used to get the right `contentElement` from the store.